# IOS progress dialog

Tags: ios, progressdialog

I want to convert an android app to iPhone. I managed to get the contents of a server by,

```
 NSString *s =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.xyz.com"];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:s];
    //    NSLog(s);
 NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
 NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
```

But, how to get the progress dialog with rotating spinner till it loads. Kindly help and oblige.

Comment: you have to add mbprogesshud in your project

Comment: Any examples of the same mate?

Comment: Lookup `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically add a simple default loading(progress) bar in iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976278/how-to-programmatically-add-a-simple-default-loadingprogress-bar-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 5):

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading";
[self doSomethingInBackgroundWithProgressCallback:^(float progress) {
    hud.progress = progress;
} completionCallback:^{
    [hud hide:YES];
}];
you have add this code
```

download source from https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD