# Is there an equivalent in iOS to the Android ProgressDialog

Tags: android, ios, progressdialog

In Android development, I use a ProgressDialog to give me a dialog with a 'spinny', some text and a cancel button. I use this combined with a CountdownTimer to perform an action after 10 seconds unless the user cancels the dialog.

I have searched around for an equivalent in iOS, such as the open source SVProgressHUD and MBProgressHUD but none seem to support the addition of a button.

Do I have to write my own, or does anyone know of an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: since IOS 9.0 UIAlertView has been deprecated. Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25671652/6042879) for an updated answer!

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
indicator.center = self.view.center;    
[self.view addSubview:indicator];
[indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
```

Write below code when you want to show indicator

```
[indicator startAnimating];
```

write below code when you want to hide indicator

```
[indicator stopAnimating];
```

was found at [How to programmatically add a simple default loading(progress) bar in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976278/how-to-programmatically-add-a-simple-default-loadingprogress-bar-in-iphone-app)

**UPD**: you can create alert dialog without buttons and add any custom elements manually:

```
UIAlertView *alert;

...

alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\nConfiguring Preferences\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil]; //display without any btns
// alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\nConfiguring Preferences\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil]; //to display with cancel btn
[alert show];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

// Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
[indicator startAnimating];
[alert addSubview:indicator];
```

To dismiss alert, just do

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

More information at: http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/uialertview-without-buttons-please-wait-dialog.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but whilst this shows a spinny which I can later dismiss, it doesn't give the option of a cancel button.

Comment: updated answer with new approach

Comment: That did it, thank you, one change needed in order to show the cancel button: alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\nConfiguring Preferences\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];

Comment: you can mark answer as "solved my question" if it really did so

Comment: Done, I was just editing my comment with the required amendment.

Comment: Added your code snippet to answer as well.

Comment: since IOS 9.0 UIAlertView has been deprecated. Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25671652/6042879) for an updated answer!